# Browsing JMS Durable Subscription

Tags: jms-topic

One of the projects I'm on is currently using a JMS Topic setup, with the client application using containing listeners for two different durable subscribers.

Long story short, we're looking at several different ways to solve an ordering issue, and one of those is by looking at JMSTimestamps. At first we were thinking we might use whatever is the durable sub equivalent of a QueueBrowser, but so far I haven't found anything.

Is there any way to accomplish either browsing the contents of a durable subscription, or seeing the next message without actually consuming it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS does not provide any API to browse messages. However there is [TopicBrowser](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b12023/oracle/jms/TopicBrowser.html) interface which is Oracle-specific extension to JMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JMSToolBox on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox) to subscribe to the Topic in parallel of your regular clients and capture all the messages post to that topic